# Scrapy SplashRequest and broken PNGs

Tags: scrapy, png, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to use Scrapy-Splash to take a screenshot of a website using the 'render.png' endpoint (in practice I do this in my spider after certain exceptions occur, and I want to view how the site looks for them).

The problem I'm having is that the response appears to not be a valid PNG. A min example in the scrapy shell is:

```
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

url='http://www.waitrose.com'

args={'wait': 2, 'width': 320, 'timeout': 60, 'render_all': 1}

endpoint='render.png'

# I also tried with dont_send_headers=True, dont_process_response=True
sr=SplashRequest(url=url, args=args, endpoint=endpoint)

fetch(sr)
```

You will need a local splash server running to execute this of course (see [here](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash/))

The response headers are

```
{'Content-Type': 'image/png',
 'Date': 'Mon, 10 Apr 2017 21:23:48 GMT',
 'Server': 'TwistedWeb/16.1.1'}
```

but the body starts like

```
In [16]: response.body[:100]
Out[16]: '<html><head></head><body>\xe2\x80\xb0PNG\n\x1a\n\nIHDR\x01@\x04\xc2\xad\x08\x065r\xe2\x80\x9aQ\tpHYs\x0fa\x0fa\x01\xc2\xa8?\xc2\xa7i IDATx\x01\xc3\xac\xc2\xbd\x07\xc5\x93\\\xc3\x97u\xc3\xa6y\xc2\xaa\xc2\xbab\xc3\xa7\xc5\x93\xc3\x91'
```

and even after trimming the html tags and saving to file, my system says non-valid PNG.

On the other hand if I use the `python-requests` module like

```
import requests                                                                     
base_url = "http://localhost:8050/render.png"
params = {'url': 'http://www.waitrosecellar.com',
          'wait': 2,
          'width': 320,
          'timeout': 60,
          'render_all': 1}
response2 = requests.get(base_url, params)
```

I have no issues. The response content starts like

```
In [19]: response2.content[:100]
Out[19]: '\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x01@\x00\x00\x03)\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00u\xf4\xea\x11\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x0fa\x00\x00\x0fa\x01\xa8?\xa7i\x00\x00 \x00IDATx\x01\xec\xbd\x07\x9c]\xc7u\xdf\x7f\xb6\x17\xec\xa2\xf7\xba(\x04A\x80`\x17\x8bH\x90\x14\x9bHY\xdd\x92l\xc9\x92\xab\\\x92'
```

the headers are

```
In [20]: response2.headers
Out[20]: {'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Date': 'Mon, 10 Apr 2017 21:39:17 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'image/png', 'Server': 'TwistedWeb/16.1.1'}
```

and saving the file produces a valid PNG image, which I can view on my system.

What is going with SplashRequest that is messing up the PNG?

I found exactly the same issue using the [screenshot pipline](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#take-screenshot-of-item) from the scrapy docs too.

EDIT: Interestingly, if I set breakpoints in the middleware process_response, the response.body is at that stage a valid PNG.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was some beautifulsoup html parser middleware I had in the chain whose 'process_response' method was messing up the png bytes.